# How do I make my GUI interface work?

Tags: java, user-interface

I am trying to make a GUI interface program which inserts the data of people like First name(Prenume), Last name(Nume) and birthday(Zi de nastere). And it has 3 buttons: Save(Salvare) which saves the data into a text file, Delete(Stergere) which deletes the data(separately for each individual put in, not all the data in the text file) and the last button which is Search(Cautare) which opens another GUI window that looks the same as the old one except it has only one button. And when you press on that button the program will search trough the text file for the string that you put in the text boxes(If you put in name text box it will search FirstName:Michael and show all persons which have the first name michael into a list made by the program also GUI. if you put the birthday he will search all the persons with that birthday) Also at the start of the program I want the program to show up a list with the persons whose birthday are in the next 10 days.

Now the biggest problem I encountered was the search box...I cant seem to make it work and I know that i need the search command to do the list at the beginning and the delete button also...cause at the delete button i need the program to search the data input and delete it from the text file. I know it might be a little confusing because the text output is in my main language which is not english but I made translations for the main words so you could understand.

Here's what I made so far:

```
JTextField camp,camp2,camp3,camp4,camp5;
String line;




Interfata()
{

    setTitle("Zile De Nastere");

    setSize(340, 200);

    setLocationRelativeTo(null);
    setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

    JPanel container = (JPanel) getContentPane();
    container.setLayout(null);

    JLabel intro = new JLabel();

    intro.setText("Nume:");

    intro.setBounds(67, 15, 100, 22);

    container.add(intro);


    camp = new JTextField("Numele");
    camp.setBounds(110,15,220,22);
    container.add(camp);


    JLabel intro2 = new JLabel();     
    intro2.setText("Prenume:");
    intro2.setBounds(48, 45, 100, 22);
    container.add(intro2);  


    camp2 = new JTextField("Prenumele");
    camp2.setBounds(110,45,220,22);
    container.add(camp2);


    JLabel intro3 = new JLabel();     
    intro3.setText("Data de nastere:");
    intro3.setBounds(10, 75, 100, 22);
    container.add(intro3);  


    camp3 = new JTextField("zi");
    camp3.setHorizontalAlignment(JTextField.CENTER);
    camp3.setBounds(110,75,20,22);
    container.add(camp3);

    JLabel cp2 = new JLabel();     
    cp2.setText("/");
    cp2.setBounds(132, 75, 15, 22);
    container.add(cp2);

    camp4 = new JTextField("luna");
    camp4.setBounds(137,75,30,22);
    camp4.setHorizontalAlignment(JTextField.CENTER);
    container.add(camp4);

    JLabel cp3 = new JLabel();     
    cp3.setText("/");
    cp3.setBounds(169, 75, 15, 22);
    container.add(cp3);

    camp5 = new JTextField("an");
    camp5.setBounds(174,75,35,22);
    camp5.setHorizontalAlignment(JTextField.CENTER);
    container.add(camp5);


    JButton go = new JButton("Salvare");
    go.setBounds(10,105,100,22);
    container.add(go);


    go.addActionListener(this);


    JButton go2 = new JButton("Stergere");
    go2.setBounds(120,105,100,22);
    container.add(go2);
    go2.addActionListener(this);    


    JButton go3 = new JButton("Cautare");
    go3.setBounds(230,105,100,22);
    container.add(go3);
    go3.addActionListener(this);


    JLabel cp = new JLabel();     
    cp.setText("Copyright 2014 Tache Radu");
    cp.setBounds(10, 140, 200, 22);
    container.add(cp);
}




    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
    {  

        if(e.getActionCommand()=="Salvare")
        {
              try {

                        File statText = new File("E:/Eclipse/Workspace/Proiect Tache Radu/Baza de Date.txt");
                        FileOutputStream is = new FileOutputStream(statText,true);
                        OutputStreamWriter osw = new OutputStreamWriter(is);    
                        Writer w = new BufferedWriter(osw);
                        String a=camp.getText();
                        String b=camp2.getText();
                        String c=camp3.getText();
                        String d=camp4.getText();
                        String f=camp5.getText();
                        int ok=1;
                        if(f.equalsIgnoreCase(""))
                            f="Nespecificat";
                        if(a.equalsIgnoreCase(""))
                        {

                            setTitle("Eroare");

                            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this,"Introduceti Numele", "Eroare", JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
                            ok=0;
                        }
                        if(b.equalsIgnoreCase(""))
                        {

                             JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this,"Introduceti Prenumele", "Eroare", JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
                            ok=0;

                        }
                        if(c.equalsIgnoreCase(""))
                        {

                             JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this,"Introduceti Ziua", "Eroare", JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
                            ok=0;

                        }

                        if(d.equalsIgnoreCase(""))
                        {

                             JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this,"Introduceti Luna", "Eroare", JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
                            ok=0;

                        }

                       if(ok==0)

                         System.exit(0);  
                         else
                         {       
                        w.write("Nume: "+camp.getText()+"\r\nPrenume: "+camp2.getText()+"\r\nData Nasterii: "+camp3.getText()+"/"+camp4.getText()+"/"+f+"\r\n----------------------------------------\r\n\r\n");
                         }
                        w.close();
                    } catch (IOException g) {
                        System.err.println("Problem writing to the file Baza de Date.txt");
                    }
                }


        if(e.getActionCommand()=="Stergere")
        {

            String s1=camp.getText();
            String s2=camp2.getText();
            String s3=camp3.getText();
            String s4=camp4.getText();
            String s5=camp5.getText();

            try {

                File inFile = new File("Baza de Date.txt");

                if (!inFile.isFile()) {
                  System.out.println("Parameter is not an existing file");
                  return;
                }

                //Construct the new file that will later be renamed to the original filename. 
                File tempFile = new File(inFile.getAbsolutePath() + ".tmp");

                BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("temp.tmp"));
                PrintWriter pw = new PrintWriter(new FileWriter(tempFile));

                String line = null;

                //Read from the original file and write to the new 
                //unless content matches data to be removed.
                while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {

                    if (!line.trim().equals(s1)) {

                        pw.println(line);
                        pw.flush();
                      }
                    if (!line.trim().equals(s2)) {

                        pw.println(line);
                        pw.flush();
                      }
                    if (!line.trim().equals(s3)) {

                        pw.println(line);
                        pw.flush();
                      }
                }
                pw.close();
                br.close();

                //Delete the original file
                if (!inFile.delete()) {
                  System.out.println("Could not delete file");
                  return;
                } 

                //Rename the new file to the filename the original file had.
                if (!tempFile.renameTo(inFile))
                  System.out.println("Could not rename file");

              }
              catch (FileNotFoundException ex) {
                ex.printStackTrace();
              }
              catch (IOException ex) {
                ex.printStackTrace();
              }
            }





        if(e.getActionCommand()=="Cautare")
        {
            JFrame Register = new JFrame("Cautare");


            Register.setTitle("Cautare");


            Register.setSize(340, 200);


            Register.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
            Register.setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);


            JPanel container = (JPanel) getContentPane();
            container.setLayout(null);


            JLabel intro7 = new JLabel();


            intro7.setText("Nume:");

            intro7.setBounds(67, 15, 100, 22);


            container.add(intro7);


            camp.setBounds(110,15,220,22);
            container.add(camp);


            JLabel intro2 = new JLabel();     
            intro2.setText("Prenume:");
            intro2.setBounds(48, 45, 100, 22);
            container.add(intro2);  


            camp2.setBounds(110,45,220,22);
            container.add(camp2);


            JLabel intro3 = new JLabel();     
            intro3.setText("Data de nastere:");
            intro3.setBounds(10, 75, 100, 22);
            container.add(intro3);  


            camp3.setHorizontalAlignment(JTextField.CENTER);
            camp3.setBounds(110,75,20,22);
            container.add(camp3);

            JLabel cp2 = new JLabel();     
            cp2.setText("/");
            cp2.setBounds(132, 75, 15, 22);
            container.add(cp2);

            camp4.setBounds(137,75,30,22);
            camp4.setHorizontalAlignment(JTextField.CENTER);
            container.add(camp4);

            JLabel cp3 = new JLabel();     
            cp3.setText("/");
            cp3.setBounds(169, 75, 15, 22);
            container.add(cp3);

            camp5.setBounds(174,75,35,22);
            camp5.setHorizontalAlignment(JTextField.CENTER);
            container.add(camp5);


            JButton go4 = new JButton("Cautare");
            go4.setBounds(120,105,100,22);
            container.add(go4);
            go4.addActionListener(this);

            if(e.getActionCommand()=="Cautare")
            {
                String a=camp.getText();
                String b=camp2.getText();
                String c=camp3.getText();
                String d=camp4.getText();
                String f=camp5.getText();

                double count = 0,countBuffer=0,countLine=0;
                String lineNumber = "";
                String filePath = "E://Eclipse/Workspace/Proiect Tache Radu/Baza de Date.txt";
                BufferedReader br;
                String inputSearch = a;
                String inputSearch2 = b;
                String inputSearch3 = c;
                String inputSearch4 = d;
                String inputSearch5 = f;
                String line = "";

                try {
                    br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(filePath));
                    try {
                        while((line = br.readLine()) != null)
                        {
                            countLine++;
                            //System.out.println(line);
                            String[] words = line.split(" ");

                            for (String word : words) {
                              if (word.equals(inputSearch) || word.equals(inputSearch2) || word.equals(inputSearch3) || word.equals(inputSearch4) || word.equals(inputSearch5)) {
                                count++;
                                countBuffer++;
                              }
                            }

                            if(countBuffer > 0)
                            {
                                countBuffer = 0;
                                lineNumber += countLine + ",";
                            }

                        }
                        br.close();
                    } catch (IOException h) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                        h.printStackTrace();
                    }
                } catch (FileNotFoundException h) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    h.printStackTrace();
                }

                System.out.println("Times found at--"+count);
                System.out.println("Word found at--"+lineNumber);
            }



            Register.setVisible(true);


            }
    }




    public static void main(String[] args) {

        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                Interfata interfata = new Interfata();
                interfata.setVisible(true);
                Interfata Stergere = new Interfata();



            }
        });
    }
}
```

Edit: I have managed to do the Delete(Stergere) button but instead of deleting just the data I want it deletes everything.

Comment: if this were visual basic, it would probably track down an IP address.

Answer (score 0):

The usual solution for problems like this one is to create a helper class which implements the UI operations (edit, delete, search). The UI then talks to this class.

Internally, the class uses a text file to actually save the data. But the UI never knows. It just calls `add()` with some parameters.

The next step is that you should define a data class which contains the data you want to process (i.e. everything about a single person: Names, dates, etc.).

Lastly, you need to write conversion methods that convert between the text file and the data class(es).

Comment: The save button is actually the only one that works...The big problem is with the search one.

Comment: also the big problem about it is that I don't know how to make the code to work. I don't know for example what to write to make the button pop up a new window with the search options(the command that does the pop up)

Comment: I guess you're a beginner at software development. The main skill you need to develop is to cut a big task into many smaller ones. So instead of struggling with a UI with many features, you should create a new project and write a small prototype which can delete a single entry from a text file. When you have found a good solution, go back to the first project and integrate it. Then do the same for search.